# Mapping an integer bit mask

Tags: c#, dictionary, mask, bit

I have an integer input representing a 32 bit mask.

This mask goes alongside a string array of length 32.

Sometimes the string array will contain nulls or empty strings. In these situations I would like to "remove" the null-or-empty-string bit from from the mask.

This mapping would involve shifting all subsequent bits to the right:

```
"d" "c" null "a" -> "d" "c" "a"

 1 1 1 1         ->  0 1 1 1
```

Finally, I would like to be able to unmap this mask when I'm finished with it. In this case I would be inserting zeroes wherever a null-or-empty-string exists in the string array.

The string array does not change between these mappings, so I am not concerned about the data becoming desynchronised.

Without using LINQ or lambda expressions, how can I implement these methods?

```
private static readonly string[] m_Names;

public static int MapToNames(int mask)
{
}

public static int MapFromNames(int mask)
{
}
```

I have been looking a little at the BitArray class, but it doesn't seem very helpful as it doesn't provide methods for converting to/from an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the answer of your question, but think about saving bit mask values in `integer` field like a sum of all bit mask fields. It is easy to control and maintain. How to check for the bit mask values.

```
if(bitmaskIntValue & value)
{

}
```

Example: You have bitmaskIntValue = 10-> 2^1 + 2^3

```
if(bitmaskIntValue & 2)
{
   //first or second input is checked.(depending from where you start 2^0 or 2^1)
}
```